# In Excel VBA how can I enable comments on a protected sheet but still protect form controls

Tags: excel, vba, comments, worksheet, spreadsheet-protection

I have a protected Excel sheet. It has form controls and I have assigned macros to them.  I can enable comments on this sheet by using

```
.Protect DrawingObjects:=False
```

but this also allows any form controls to be deleted.

I could change the form controls to activeX controls but this would prevent Mac users using it.

Is there a way of enabling comments but protecting the form controls?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way of enabling comments but protecting the form controls?

Not that I know of. But you may come up with a workaround :)
Like this:

- build a form, that has a text box and a button. Call the form with a shortcut, it would be easier;
- select the cell you want to insert a comment to and call the form;
- write the comment inside the form and press the button;

Something like this may be put in the code of the form. `commentCell` is the selected cell. Probably some check how many cells are selected can be added as well:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=sPassword
Range(commentCell.Address).AddComment
Range(commentCell.Address).Comment.Text Text:=MyComment
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=sPassword
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  Yeah that's an option.  the spreadsheet is 3000 rows and 150 odd columns so it's going to be annoying for the user to have to navigate back to a button for every cell they want to comment in.  Alternatively I could check if a control has been deleted and undo the action but it doesn't appear to trigger a sheet event when a control is deleted.